# Why does my viewport have parts that don't show the axes?

Tags: 3d-view, error, artifacts

I have a mildly annoying problem where my viewport doesn't show the axes uniformly as it should. At certain distances, parts of my axes disappear as if following a pattern. Seems like a glitch?

[image]

I tried changing the "clip end" under the view panel to a much larger value(10000m) but it didn't help too. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: This seems interesting. Could you upload the file?

Comment: maybe you have a wave modifier on your plane/geometry?